# Redshift PostgreSQL window function - keep most recent non-null value

Tags: aggregate-functions, amazon-redshift

Here's my data:

```
+--------+------------+---------+------------+----------------+
| UserID | VisitDate  | VisitID | PurchaseID | LastPurchaseID |
+--------+------------+---------+------------+----------------+
|   1234 | 2014-10-03 |       1 | 4a75       | 4a75           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-06 |       2 |            | 4a75           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-07 |       3 | b305       | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-08 |       4 |            | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-09 |       5 |            | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-10 |       6 | b305       | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-10 |       7 |            | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-15 |       8 |            | b305           |
+--------+------------+---------+------------+----------------+
```

**I don't have LastPurchaseID - this is what I want**

I figure I have to use window functions, but I'm not sure how to get it to keep the most recent non-null value, even if the most recent non-null value is many rows ago.

For example, I've tried something like:

```
SELECT UserID,
       VisitDate,
       VisitID,
       PurchaseID,
       LAG(TRIM(PurchaseID)) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER (ORDER BY UserID, VisitDate) AS LastPurchaseID
FROM TheTable;
```

but this only returns:

```
+--------+------------+---------+------------+----------------+
| UserID | VisitDate  | VisitID | PurchaseID | LastPurchaseID |
+--------+------------+---------+------------+----------------+
|   1234 | 2014-10-03 |       1 | 4a75       | 4a75           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-06 |       2 |            | 4a75           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-07 |       3 | b305       | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-08 |       4 |            | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-09 |       5 |            |                |
|   1234 | 2014-10-10 |       6 | b305       | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-10 |       7 |            | b305           |
|   1234 | 2014-10-15 |       8 |            |                |
+--------+------------+---------+------------+----------------+
```

Is there any way to use a window function say "keep the most recent, if it is null, assume it hasn't changed from the previous non-null value"?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got it, sorry about that. For anyone else in this somewhat unique situation, this is what was happening:

Since `PurchaseID` was a string in my case, I wasn't considering the case where the `PurchaseID` was an empty string (or just a space, which `trim()` turned into the empty string), which is not null.

I have since fixed the job that inserts into the table to prevent this from occurring, and also changed the LastPurchaseID logic to the following:

```
SELECT LAG(CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(PurchaseID)) = 0 THEN NULL
                ELSE TRIM(PurchaseID) END)
           IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY UserID, VisitDate) AS LastPurchaseID
FROM TheTable;
```